# Preventing debugger when value is deleted from VBA textbox

Tags: vba, excel, textbox, excel-2013

My user form has several textbox's that can be edited by the user but it was reported to me that it was debugging. After a bit of investigation i found that the user was deleting the value out of the text box and this was causing a run-time error 13. How do i stop the run-time error if the user deletes the value and the `servcredit` textbox becomes a `vbnullstring`?

at present the text box has the 2 below pieces of code.

**This inputs the numerical value into the excel sheets in the back.**

```
Private Sub ServCredit_Change()

Worksheets("Calculator").Range("L18") = CDec(ServCredit)

End Sub
```

**This ensure the user doesn't input a none numerical figure.**

```
Private Sub ServCredit_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)

If (KeyAscii > 47 And KeyAscii < 58) Or KeyAscii = 46 Or KeyAscii = 32 Then
KeyAscii = KeyAscii
Else
KeyAscii = 0
MsgBox "Invalid Key Pressed"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply test if there is a value:

```
Private Sub ServCredit_Change()

If Len(ServCredit.Text) <> 0 then
   Worksheets("Calculator").Range("L18").Value2 = CDec(ServCredit)
Else
   Worksheets("Calculator").Range("L18").Value2 = vbnullstring
end if
End Sub
```

Comment: but this sets `Worksheets("Calculator").Range("L18")` to be the last value that was entered in `ServCredit` this might result in wrong calculations. If the textbox value was e.g. `152` and you use backspace to remove all 3 digits then L18 will remain `1`. Safest way would be to check against numeric and set it `0` if it is not. Your solution relies on that only number can be entered.

Comment: @Peh I agree it would be better to clear the cell. The question makes it clear that the control is already validated to prevent non-numeric entry.

Comment: Yes but there is still a vulnerability; it's not safe against VBA injections like `ServCredit.Text = "aa"` from any other sub or function. This will also trigger the change event and will cause an exception. Any false input to a function (in this case the text box) should not end up in an unhandled exception, but here it does. `cdec` expects numeric so I test against numeric.

Comment: True, but I assume the developer will be aware if his code does that.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to check if `ServCredit` is numeric. `CDec` cannot cast a vbNullString into a number.

```
If IsNumeric(ServCredit) then
    Worksheets("Calculator").Range("L18") = CDec(ServCredit)
else
    Worksheets("Calculator").Range("L18") = 0
End If
```